# How to define the constant _DEBUG in c++

Tags: c++

When I compile and execute thes code, I get...

```
_DEBUG IS NOT defined
```

Why isn't the constant being shown as defined?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
  const bool _DEBUG = true;
  #if defined _DEBUG
    std::cout << "_DEBUG IS defined\n";
  #else
    std::cout << "_DEBUG IS NOT defined\n";
  #endif // _DEBUG
}
```

Comment: Because it is not defined at preprocessor stage.

Comment: Anything that starts with `#` only cares about things that start with `#`.

Comment: Also, `_DEBUG` is a special macro name that is normally defined by the build configuration (Your Visual Studio project settings, CMake, etc.). If you're adding `#define _DEBUG` anywhere in your code you're likely going to enable debug code sections in release builds! That can lead to lower performance, loading multiple C++ runtimes, or just completely break your program. Keep in mind that the standard C++ library has checks for `_DEBUG` written throughout its headers.

Comment: @Romen More broadly, any identifier that begins with an underscore and that is followed by an uppercase letter is reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define _DEBUG
```

or

```
#define _DEBUG       1
```

The second method can be checked with `#ifdef _DEBUG` or `#if _DEBUG`. Usually `_DEBUG` is defined in compiler IDE profile.

Comment: The first can be checked with `#ifdef _DEBUG`, `#ifndef _DEBUG`, and with `#if defined(_DEBUG)`.

Comment: Identifiers that starts with an underscore and that is followed by an uppercase letter are reserved. You aren't allowed to `#define _DEBUG`.

Comment: Can you define _DEBUG when you run the script? For example... $ ./script _DEBUG=1

Answer (score 1):

`#if defined TOKEN` only checks if `TOKEN` is defined as a [preprocessor macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), i.e. with `#define TOKEN ...`.  Here you have defined it as a (constant) variable, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`const bool _DEBUG = true;` defines a constant which is known to the compiler and not to the preprocessor.

The following check is executed by the preprocessor before the compiler kicks in, therefore it never sees `_DEBUG` constant.

```
  #if defined _DEBUG
    std::cout << "_DEBUG IS defined\n";
  #else
    std::cout << "_DEBUG IS NOT defined\n";
  #endif // _DEBUG
```

To get rid of the issue, you should `#define _DEBUG` so that the preprocessor knows about the token.